# How to access files in public_html through the subdomain folder

Tags: php

I have a website called [www.meagl.com](http://www.meagl.com) ...In this, I created a sub-domain called m.meagl.com.

My public_html folder contains two folders called users and groups.

What I wish to do is access these folders through my sub-domain folders in php to get the images that I have stored in them.
To do this, I add "../" to the existing file destinations in the sub-domain files wherever necessary. Example:to access `users/sharvai/78.jpg`, I wrote `../users/sharvai/78.jpg`. But no images are being loaded onto my sub-domain.

Please help!!

Comment: How did you create the subdomain? How are you attempting to load the images? What is the path to the images?

Comment: I created the subdomain in c-panel..this created a folder called "m.meagl.com"...To load the images, I used <img> tags. And the source is like "users/(username)/(image id).extension"..This lies in the public_html folder

Comment: A domain name and a folder on some server's hard drive are two entirely different things. How they relate to one another is determined by DNS and web server configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:

I was initially thinking about this as if you were dealing with a .php file dependency. That was the wrong way to think about it. You are talking about images. Images, whether inline img tags or CSS backgrounds are served over http://. Therefore, you need to use a valid URL. Based on the information you have supplied, you want to use URLs like:

```
http://www.meagle.com/users/75.jpg
```

Shame on me for not realising this sooner.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: So users and groups and m.meagl.com all lie in public_html. I did try using ./../users/foo.jpg but its not working

Comment: @KlaraNewbie did you figure it out? If not, please take one specific example and list list the path of the php file and image file relative to public_html

Comment: I couldnt figure it out! Ohkay so suppose I have a file called 78.jpg. Now I have a folder called users in public_html. Also, I have a folder for the subdomain called m.meagl.com in public_html itself. Now suppose if I have a file called functions.php in which I wish to access the image(78.jpg) from the users folder, how will I do it? The path of the image file from the public html folder is "users/78.jpg" and the path of the file which intends to access this image is "m.meagl.com/functions.php". Here, m.meagl.com is in the public_html folder. By the way, thank you so much for the follow up!:)

Comment: Assuming the following paths: 'public_html/m.meagle.com/functions.php' and 'public_html/users/78.jpg' the path used by functions.php should be './../users/78.jpg'.

Comment: Okayy sure gimme a sec

Comment: begin the url with http://www. I typed that in my comment but it's not displaying

Comment: Should I include the pre tags too?

Comment: no, sorry. The comment isn't displaying the way I type it. start with http. then add the colon slash slash followed by www dot, then meagle.com/users/78.jpg. when I type that out as a proper URL it only displays the part beginning with meagle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154043/discussion-between-klaranewbie-and-neil-girardi).

Answer (score 1):

Files outside of public_html are protected from being seen on the web. Many people use that feature as a security to their content. If you have a file on there that you want to show contents of though, you have to use the include('file.php'); or include_once('file.php'); or even require_once('file.php') in a public ally visible file. Aka a file you have in public_html has to be the one to call the higher up file. If I am understanding your question right, that is how it is supposed to be done.

Comment: So does that mean that I can't access the folders in public_html from the subdomain folder?

Comment: Easy solution upload the same files to subdomain folder too.

Comment: But what if the users are uploading the files from the subdomain?

Comment: Then you link the files on the subdomain. The files are available through the domain they're hosted on, unless you link the files physically to the other home directory on disk (through a symlink or something similar)